# Getting substring of python string removing escape character

Tags: python-3.x

I have following code:

```
test = 'abc {\"hello\":\"world\"}'
test1 = test[test.find('{'):]
print(test1)
```

I am looking to get back: `{\"hello\":\"world\"}`
But above code is removing escape characters, is there a way to keep these escape characters in the substring?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, this might help someone:

```
test = r'abc {\"hello\":\"world\"}'
test1 = test[test.find('{'):]
print(test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra "\" before each "\"

`test = 'abc {\\"hello\\":\\"world\\"}'`
`test1 = test[test.find('{'):]`
`print(test1)`

the output is now `{\"hello\":\"world\"}`

Comment: I cannot change test